# CSS3 Transform to Trapezoid

Tags: css, css-transforms

I need to create a CSS3 trapezoid using a div element. To make it crystal clear what I'm doing I've created a basic visual below; green is a normal rectangular div while the red represents the parts I need to change the div to in order to achieve the trapezoid shape I need.

[image: Green is normal rectangle div, red the expanded trapezoid area of the div]

Provided that we're editing `.trapezoid {}` CSS class what are the rules I need to achieve the shape? (Obviously the color is just reference).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
.trapezoid { transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-45deg) scale(1.1,1.1); }
```

Adjust values as necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I edited your post because you forgot to add the `transform` property to the class and was initially wondering why I had a rectangle.