# Interlocking Trapezoid CSS3

Tags: css

I've been trying to use transform like [CSS3 Transform to Trapezoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481232/css3-transform-to-trapezoid) to achieve the look in my attached photo.

I am having trouble making them interlock cleanly as per my crappy wireframe. Also making the background of them a slightly opaque photo having the ability to adjust the images position easily.

Any help is much appreciated!

Current: http://cssdeck.com/labs/lrjtihdm

2

[crappy wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0h8z.jpg)

Comment: What does your HTML look like? What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Right now I am just building out the basic structure so just empty divs.

Comment: Okay... What have you tried? What was the result? Can you include a picture or http://jsfiddle.com of what you have?

Comment: If you put it in your question then you can format it.

Comment: @Omninero Please [edit] your question to include relevant details, instead of posting them into comments.

Comment: Sorry, new to the site/ and html/css in general. Just finished the Codecademy course, trying out my first project on my own.